# How to Radius corner of Rectangle object in android

Tags: android

I want to rounded the corner of rectangle in Android code.
I am using:

```
Rectangle mRectangle = new Rectangle(value1, value2, value3, value4);
mRectangle.setColor(1f, 0.01f, 0.02f);
```

So, my question is, how can I rounded the corner of rectangle from above code?

Thanks You,

Answer (score 1):

do it this way

```
Paint p = new Paint();
p.Color = Color.White;
canvas.DrawColor(Color.DarkOrange);

Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,3,3);

RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);


canvas.DrawRoundRect( rectF, 1,1, p);
```